# Why is .each() not working in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a column of buttons. When a user clicks a button I want to show a message, and hide it after a few seconds.

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/8pqaz7h3/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>
</div
```

**D3**

```
d3.select(".add")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.selectAll(".message")
      .each(function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 1)
          .text("added");
     })
   })
```

I have 2 issues:

1. When the 'add' button is clicked all the messages show, instead of the one beside the clicked button. Is there something wrong with the way I've used `.each`?
2. I can't hide the message after some duration. I tried using `delay` and `fadeOut` but it broke the entire function.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Snippet**

```js
d3.selectAll(".add")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.selectAll(".message")
      .each(function() {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 1)
          .text("added");
      })
  })
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper div {
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  right: -60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: To question 1: the problem is not `.each()` but `.selectAll()`. "Get all elements with class `message` (= `selectAll(".message")`) and show them one by one (`.each()`). Instead select the clicked element (`.select(this)`) and then find the `.message` element (`.select(".message")`)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, that makes sense. It stops all messages from displaying at the same time, but will only show the first message now, no matter which button is clicked ---> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/sub9kw8d/1/ --  I'm not sure what's gone wrong

Comment: You don't need the `.each()`. `.select(this)` only returns one element. And you should get the `.message` element which is a child of `this` -> `select(this).select(".message")` - https://jsfiddle.net/sub9kw8d/3/

Comment: oh.. I see now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would code it:

```
d3.selectAll(".add")
    .on("click", function() {
      var m = d3.select(this.children[0]);
      m.text("added")
        .style("opacity", 1);
      m.transition()
        .delay(500)
        .duration(1000)
        .style("opacity", 0);
   });
```

Running:

```js
d3.selectAll(".add")
  .on("click", function() {
    var m = d3.select(this.children[0]);
    m.text("added")
      .style("opacity", 1);
    m.transition()
      .delay(500)
      .duration(1000)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  })
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper div {
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  right: -60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="add">
    Add
    <span class="message"></span>
  </div>

</div>
```